# Indian rupee symbol in xetex

Tags: xetex

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tfrupee}
\begin{document}
The sales were ₹500,000,000 (\$200,000) in FY2016.

The sales were \rupee~500,000,000 (\$200,000) in FY2016.
\end{document}
```

With `tfrupee` package, it is possible to print the Indian Rupee symbol. But that requires \rupee to be used in place of the symbol.

Is not there a way to print ₹ character directly?

Comment: You can, if you use a font which has this symbol (ebgaramond has, for instance).

Comment: @Bernard is there an easy way of getting a list of fonts (preferably with preview) available for latex that contains the rupee sign?

Comment: I don't know of any such list. If the font has an opentype (.otf or .ttf) version, any font manager will tell if a given font has this sign. These fonts have it (not comprehensive): Linux Libertine O, DejaVu, ebgaramond, cormorant garamond, merriweather, roboto. Also Minion Pro and Myriad Pro that come with Acrobat Reader. **Not** cm unicode, nor Latin Modern, TeX Gyre, GSF fonts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `newunicode` package to define the `₹` symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tfrupee}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
  \newunicodechar{₹}{\rupee}

\begin{document}
The sales were ₹500,000,000 (\$200,000) in FY2016.
The sales were \rupee~500,000,000 (\$200,000) in FY2016.
\end{document}
```

This would also work with `pdflatex` with `utf8` input encoding (i.e., `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`).

Comment: The OP is using XeLaTeX, so loading `inputenc` is not needed.

Comment: @egreg I had not spotted the `xetex` tag, thanks.